Meaning of "under look"
What's the meaning of "under look" in the text below?
Byron the philhellene is but one Byron among many. The limping boy, the wag with the bear, the cad with the under look, the Londoner, the libertine, the would-be liberator: take your pick.

Where did you see this?

In an article about Lord Byron published by the website newyorker. The address is https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2024/03/04/byron-a-life-in-ten-letters-andrew-stauffer-book-review, but unfortunately it is an exclusive article for subscribers and access for non-subscribers is only allowed for a few seconds.

The title is Lord Byron was more than Byronic, but the article includes, earlier: "But Byron (italics)was(italics) Byronic. One observer, Lady Mildmay, is said to have felt the full force: 'Once, when he spoke to her in a doorway, her heart beat so violently that she could hardly answer him. She said it was not only her awe of his great talents, but the peculiarity of a sort of (italics)under(italics) look he used to give, that produced this effect upon her.'" It does not say who is quoting/paraphrasing Lady Mildmay there.

Quite apart from the fact that we can't access the full context of this decidedly obscure text, I don't think this question is useful to other people wishing to learn English. Maybe it belongs on SE Literature, but we have no migration route for that.

@Sydney - to produce an italic effect, simply place an underscore character ( _ ) immediately before and after the text that you wish to so appear.

I’m voting to close this question because it's not really connected to "learning English" - it's about literature and biographies.

I'd guess it's a (possibly fatuous) "fresh" alternative to cliched piercing look and penetrating gaze - that see under the skin, below the surface, through the mask. The supposed speaker is named from Lady Mildmay's Journal, begun in the early 1610s, but Byron wasn't born until 1788, so it's all just fanciful made up references "in the style of" biography (hagiography! :)

@FumbleFingers The text is not obscure. It is literary. Geesus. It should not be closed and I think you should stop telling learners what they need to learn.

British author: https://www.greenbelt.org.uk/artists/helen-seymour-2/ The Underlook

Please edit the extra info into the question itself, not just a comment.

The most flamboyant and notorious of the major Romantics, George Gordon, Lord Byron, was likewise the most fashionable poet of the day. He created an immensely popular Romantic hero--defiant, melancholy, haunted by secret guilt--for which, to many, he seemed the model.

@FumbleFingers - There has been more than one Lady Mildmay! This must be this one.

OP: What's the meaning of "under look" in the text below?
Byron the philhellene is but one Byron among many. The limping boy, the wag with the bear, the cad with the under look, the Londoner, the libertine, the would-be liberator: take your pick.
Merriam Webster underlook =
: to look or glance at from underneath or from lowered eyes : look covertly at
Even The New Yorker sometimes gets it wrong. I'd consider it a typo.


By comparison with overlook, underlook actually flatlines on NGrams.. 2) The more common meaning (of a relatively rare word) is OED definition to miss seeing by looking too low (effectively, a variant of overlook). 3) What little currency underlook ever had was two centuries ago. 3) My spellchecker underlines it in red! ELL???!!!


@Lambie: I'm not sure: are you saying it was probably a two-word typo for the single word "underlook," used as a noun with a meaning that we can probably extrapolate from this M-W verb definition? Or that there should be no such noun and the author got hold of the wrong end of this verb? I definitely think that this meaning is the most fit one. To glance from lowered eyes is hella Byronic.

@AndyBonner: I'd say the "glance from lowered eyes" is trademark demure Princess Diana - the precise opposite of Byron's "larger than life" flamboyant character. I honestly don't think there's anything to be learned about English from the confused text being presented here.

There's a sly glance (Byron) and shy glance (Princess Diana).

@AndyBonner I mean a single typo. One space shouldn't be there. //And overlook has zero to do with it. ngrams is meaningless here. It proves nothing at all. Not everything has already "been used".

It should mean 'an unattractive appearance'.
Since it's from the phrase 'the cad with the under look', it should have something to do with the word 'cad', which means 'a low-bred, presuming person; a mean, vulgar fellow, especially one that cannot be trusted with a lady' according to wiktionary. Usually, we would expect a flamboyant playboy to be handsome, but this is not the case for Byron. According to this blog, titled The Byronic look: overweight and unattractive,

When a man is noted for his Byronic looks he is generally chuffed – dark, handsome, attractively unavailable. Slightly morose, it's true, but in a sexy way.
The reality though should now be amended to overweight, not at all attractive and thoroughly unpleasant. Or, as historian Lucy Worsley puts it: "Self-regarding poser."

The phrase you quoted is actually using the paradox-like sense to make the language more poetic.
Edited:
I seemed to be wrong. According to ChatGPT,

In the context provided, "the cad with the under look" seems to be a more poetic or literary usage rather than a standard phrase. Here, "under look" could imply a sly, secretive, or perhaps deceitful expression or demeanor. It's describing a particular aspect of Byron's character or appearance, suggesting a look that might be associated with a lack of trustworthiness or moral ambiguity.

